# How to active VSTO Word Add-Ins?

Tags: c#, vsto, installshield-2015

I have created VSTO Word Add-Ins. It provides extra Tab for formatting. I have created setup file by InstallShield Windows Installer.

I have installed setup and it installed successfully. But it doesn't show the extra Tab.

Do I need to active that Add-Ins from Ms Word? Or Is there any setting need to do to get functionality of the Add-Ins?

Can any body suggest me what I am missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTO Add-In: Exception- Value does not fall within the expected range Office 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277439/vsto-add-in-exception-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-office-201)

Comment: @CindyMeister That is also my post. For above solution, I have followed as JamesDill said in below answer. But I throws 2-3 different types of Exceptions. So, I post Exception in different Ticket as I don't know How to post Whole exception in Comment.

Comment: Use the [edit] link in the original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your installshield setup, it is likely it's simply not doing what is needed (regardless of whether it "installed").  The key points are to make sure you set you have added the correct registry keys, and the vsto/files are in the correct location.

Recommend double checking any setting:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx

Note, depending on whether it's 64/32 bit, the registry/default locations are different.

Comment: In case of Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer, Do I need to set any certificate or grant?

Comment: Providing the installer has access to the registry and file location, no other certificate is required.

Comment: After Installation of it, Do I need to Active new Add-In from Ms Word manually? Or it will directly show the newly added Add-In(New Ribbon Tab in my case)?

Comment: If you have setup the files/registry settings correctly, no manual intervention is required.

Comment: Thank you James. It is working fine in Office 2013. But it throws following error in Office 2010. From: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyGrammar/EasyGrammar/EasyGrammar.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.