# VSTO Add-In: Exception- Value does not fall within the expected range Office 2010

Tags: vsto, office-interop

I have created Word Add-In. I have created Installer Setup of it. I have installed it. It is working fine in Office 2007, 2013, 2016. But it is not working in Office 2010.

It throws following error. Can Anybody suggest me how to resolve it?

```
From: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyGrammar/EasyGrammar/EasyGrammar.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.VSTOEENativeMethods.GetValidCompatibleFramework(String compatibleFrameworkXml)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.CompatibleFrameworksValidation.ParseFirstValidFramework(String compatibleFrameworksXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.OfficeAddInDeploymentManager.OnAddInManifestsDownloaded(AddInManifestsDownloadedArgs args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.RaiseOnAddInManifestsDownloadedEvent(IClickOnceAddInInstaller addInInstaller, Uri deploymentManifestUri, AddInInstallationStatus addinSolutionState, String productName, String deploymentManifestXml, String applicationManifestXml, String hostManifestXml, String logFilePath, String version, Uri supportUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Comment: That's a very generic error and you're probably going to have to track down the offending code yourself.

Comment: @Chris But it is working perfectly in Office 2007, 2013, 2016. Just issue in Office 2010. Can you please give me clue to find this error?

Comment: No, I can't. Nobody will be able to track down the cause except you, because the error message doesn't give enough information. All you can do is set up a development environment with Office 2010 and debug it.